# Accelerate framework ios: Fastest pythagoren calculation

Tags: ios, matrix, accelerate-framework, pythagorean

So I have 2 matrices: each is 100x100.

I am looking to calculate a 3rd matrix such that: M3[i]=sqrt(M1[i]^2 + M2[i]^2).

I can obviously do ForLoops but I am sure there is something faster.

I digged into the accelerate framework and got lost in Linpack world

Any help to get me on the right track...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accelerate framework is a good idea.

You could use a function like [vDSP_vsq](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vsq) to operate on one column of the matrix at a time, placing the result in the corresponding column of M3. You might have to make two resultant matrices (one which will be M1^2, the other M2^2), and then add them to form the correct M3 result matrix by adding the columns with a call to [vDSP_vadd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vadd) which, again, will be able to operate one column at a time.

There is sample code (showing how to add two vectors, etc) [here at the Apple developer page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-44988).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It did not seem that any vDSP functions work on int and I would have to go through a conversion to float. is That correct?

Comment: That's right - you could use another vDSP function like vDSP_vflt32 to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is to use

vDSP_vpythg
Vector Pythagoras; single precision.

Subtracts vector C from A and squares the differences, subtracts vector D from B and squares the differences, adds the two sets of squared differences, and then writes the square roots of the sums to vector E.

Obviously pass ZERO vector for C and D .